# BMP file for a banner design

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a very urgent question, I am designing a banner in Adobe Illustrator for a cafe that will be engraved on wood, its size is 350 w x 60 H. The client wants the banner as .bmp, to export the banner from Illustrator:

1. File → export as → BMP
2. What should I choose here for color? RGB or Greyscale or Bitmap?
   And for the resolution (72 or 150 or 300)?

[image]

3. I chose windows, then depth what should it be (16 or 24 or 32),
   32 is the default.

[image]

4. What about the advanced modes? Should I take care of anything
   else?

Comment: The requirement has no sense. Nobody uses BMP for... well... anything. Contact the provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. **Stop**. The requirements have no sense.

1. Almost no one uses BMP for anything.
2. A file that is 350 (Inches I assume) at 300PPI is a file of 105,000 pixels wide.

   X 60 Height is a file of 18,000 giving you a file size of 2,700 Megapixels. Add that that BMP is an uncompressed file will give you 3Mb per Megapixel... or 8100 Megabytes... **8.1 Gigabytes** on a single useless file.

---

Ask the provider what they really need.

"Engraving" can be by a router drill, which could need a vector based file, or could be laser engraved, which probably needs a grayscale or 1-bit image.

In the second case, ask for the resolution, that could be around 100PPI because the laser has no that high resolution. It will be a burning dot, not a droplet of ink... And I really doubt there is a machine big enough to engrave that wood. In fact, there is no plywood of that size, so it needs to be in sections.

---

You need to talk to the provider. **Do not prepare that nonsense file**.

Comment: 350 w x 60 H (Centimeters)

Answer (score 1):

BMP is unusual, more frequently engravings are produced from monochrome vector artwork in AI, PDF or EPS format.

Then, if everybody's sure BMP should be used, you probably need to send a black only version in 300dpi and for the rest go with the defaults.

Ask the client to ask the printer if they need any other specific settings made they should tell you that specifically. Its very likely they can confirm you can actually send the AI file you already have and skip the BMP.

Comment: so I will change the logo to black to be a monochrome, right? I tried to change from 72 dpi to 300 dpi, but it doesn't work, it says no space. I know that for large size like that banner 350 w x 60 H, it should be 72 dpi or maybe 50, what do you think?